# Dynamic input to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm working on an app that lets a user create projects custom to the users needs, the project is basically a form that can be submitted by another user.

I want to allow the user to dynamically create new fields (with Javascript) to the project (a basic form) and choose custom values for each field.

And when the project (the form) is ready it can be submitted and the user specified values goes to a database. Then another user can submit the form and the values the original user has chosen are as options for that form.

The values (that are dynamically created by the user) are most likely going to be basic data, like name, phone, email etc. But there is also options for specific data like food, address, etc. I want the user to be able to ask for any data he/she sees necessary.

So how should I structure my database? I cannot be sure what or how many fields the user is going to choose for his project, i was thinking of doing this app in a traditional relational database, most likely Postgres or Mysql.

So should a create columns for all the data I can think of (or allow user to create) or could this be done in some other way?

Comment: I'll just say, we have something like this where I work, and it's a freaking pain to mess with the code and interpret the data. If you can do what you want in a more structured way I say survey that first, but if not EAV is probably a good start.

Comment: Thank you all who took the time to answear this Q. Ill look into each solution and try to find out whats the best for this project.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model. It has some pros as you will have some flexibility to create whatever structure you want, but it has also some limitations on retrieving and querying afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your database should contain the following columns in the table for the form specs:

- name (name of the field, used as "name" attrubute of the form's input field)
- label (Description to print in the form)
- format (if you want to distinguish selects/inputs/checkboxes)
- validation (if you want a set of validation rules)
- value_type (int/string/date/etc.. - type of value to accept from user. helpful for validation)

Answer (score 1):

One possible option:

table: inputs

- **Description:** Stores different types of inputs (select, select multiple, input, checkbox, radio)
- **Fields:** `inputtypeid` (primary), `input_type`, `status`

table: fields

- **Description**: Stores individual fields that the project owner has created.
- **Fields:** `fieldid` (primary), `inputtypeid` (ref inputs), `label`

table: values

- **Description:** Stores values (default and user submitted) for fields.
- **Fields:** `valueid` (primary), `fieldid` (ref fields), `value`, `default` (bool yes/no)

table: project_forms

- **Description:** Stores a list of fields that apply to the project.
- **Fields:** `pfid` (primary), `projid` (ref project), `fieldid` (ref inputs)

One side note here. Make sure you take care not to let users store personally identifiable information into something like this. Or if you do, make sure you take the necessary precautions to safeguard that data, which is a bit different in this setup than in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation with an assessment application.  Each assessment asked a number of questions, but periodically, the question set would change.  Rather than creating a separate table with key/value pairs for the questions and answers, I took advantage of serializing in PHP.

1. Determine what data must be a part of every form (Id, submitter, submission datetime, name of project, phone)  Make those data elements columns in your table.
2. Create an additional column for the serialized data.  This is where you store the additional attributes.

(Only 1 table needed)

When it comes to displaying the form, use the serialized data to build the additional form elements that are needed.

With this model, it is difficult to search the additional data that gets stored in the serialized data, but it simplifies the development;  with thousands of records, and over 100 'questions' per assessment, we haven't run into an issue yet.